# Minimising server access with heavy javascript webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've been working on a webpage that has a PHP backend to access a database and generate the basic page HTML. Once loaded, all user interaction is controlled by javascript.

To communicate back to the server I'm using the traditional post method:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: ajaxurl,
   data: postdata,
   success: function(data) {
      // PHP returns data
   }
});
```

However, the moment I start communicating back to the server using this method, I create lag in the UI and the user experience suffers, especially if they have a slow connection. I've got the usual loading gif spinners and progress bars where appropriate, but I want the UI to be as instant as it can be.

The primary reason I'm going back to the server is to grab information from the database. I've been wondering if there are ways to remove this?

1) Download the database data and access it directly in Javascript? Completely removing to need to go to the server to retrieve data. Is this possible? Are there any libraries for this?

2) In general, are there more efficient ways to retrieve data from a server than using the post method?

Comment: It's all about when the bytes get transferred as it has to get there somehow :) Normally the load of a single page of data is relatively fast, but not if you have a slow connection or slow server/database. If you download the entire database as part of the original page your whole page will suffer a lengthy initial load, but subsequent operations will be faster. Instead you can prime the loaded page with just the first page of data from the database and let the Ajax take care of subsequent pages. Efficiency of transfer is down to the number of bytes shifted (and compression if enabled).

Comment: Some formats are more compact than others (Binary better than JSON which is better than XML which is better than HTML etc). JSON is just easy to deal with in jquery/javascript so tends to be the one used.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Downloading at the start is definitely my preference. 15 seconds or progress bar at the start would be preferable to UI that is a little 'laggy'. I'd be happy to download my data as JSON if I could query is easily enough. Is there a library that provides similar functionary to simple SQL queries for JSON data.

Comment: Most REST based systems use OData for more complex queries. It is basically primitive SQL commands on top of REST (paging, sorting etc). All trivial in .Net, but in PHP I have no clue where to start. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible solutions are to preload data where possible, turn on caching on server side if needed, optimize your queries to database, do not return whole html from POST etc.